# return empty row based on condition in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Edited:

I have a search stored procedure. The stored procedure receives a few bit parameters named @filter1, @filter2, etc. The parameters indicates if a contextual filter will be returned or not by the procedure. Yet, the procedure can return errors. Something like:

```
if error
    select * from erros
else
    select 0

if filter1
    select * from tablea
else
    select 1

select * from search
```

The `select 0` and `select 1` statements are there just to keep the search at the same position, but they cause a little of spaghetti code in the back end, because I have to check the table content to figure out if there's a error or not and evaluate several filter parameters in order to build my objects properly. It's simpler to check how many rows are inside the table.

My question is, is there a non expensive way to return a empty dataset to avoid the select 0 and select 1 statements?

Comment: where do you load the data? You can use filter in your code to load one or three datatables (for example). Evaluate the filter in your code before calling stored, and then you'll know how much data you'll need to load (one or three)

Comment: Also you can try `select top 0 * from tablea` and `select top 0 * from tableb`. That will return empty rows with the columns of `TableA` and `TableB`. If that works for you, notify me and I will put it as answer, so you can tick it !

Comment: it works! Your point about the flow is right, I can evaluate the filter to avoid more spaghetti code, but the question is malformed because I do have errors too, and the only way to know if there are errors is checking the table. Return 0 rows makes my code and job a lot easier.

Comment: The question is better now. When you post your answer I will mark it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select top 0 * from tablea
select top 0 * from tableb
```

That will return empty rows with the columns of `TableA` and `TableB`