# SELECT only the whole row where the column is empty in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

If I have the following example table, is there any way that I only keep rows where the "Closed Date" column is empty?  In this example, only the second row has an empty "Closed Date" column, the third and fourth are not. [image]

```
Unique Key,Created Date,Month,Closed Date,Latitude,Longitude
32098276,12/1/2015 0:35,12,,40.78529363,-73.96933478,"(40.78529363449518, -73.96933477605721)"
32096105,11/30/2015 20:09,11,11/30/2015 20:09,40.62615508,-73.9606431,"(40.626155084398036, -73.96064310416676)"
32098405,11/30/2015 20:08,11,11/30/2015 20:08,40.6236074,-73.95914964,"(40.62360739765128, -73.95914964173129)"
```

I find this but this is not exactly I am looking for.  Could any guru enlighten?  Thanks!

[return empty row based on condition in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002722/return-empty-row-based-on-condition-in-sql-server)

- Sorry forgot to mention I use SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Does your empty value mean `NULL` or empty string `''`? What is the type of `Closed Date` column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE [Closed Date] IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM([Closed Date])) = ''
```

Comment:  This is SQL Server specific :)

Comment: @lad2025 when I get to know the dbms, I can update the syntax :-)

Comment: I use SQL Server 2014.  If I only use "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Closed_Date IS NULL", it will only return the header without any role. What is the difference between your magic and regular IS NULL?

Comment: @Chubaka SQL Server in general displays `NULL` if the column value is null indeed. Based on your comment, I can tell with certainty that the value is not null; it is either an empty string or a string with whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IS NULL` to filter out records that contains `NULL` value:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE "Closed Date" IS NULL
```

Keep in mind that column identifier with space is bad practice. You should use something like `Closed_Date` to avoid quoting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `IS NULL` condition in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE "Closed Date" IS NULL
```

Comment:  You should add that backtick is MySQL specific :)

Comment: He really should specify his RDBMS.  But the `WHERE` construct should work in MySQL, Oracle, and SQL Server.

Comment: thats why i did not give an answer , i ask first the dbms in the OP :)

Comment: Forgot to mention I tried IS NULL like your answer, but it returns only the header.  I am not quite sure why : /

Comment: I used SQL server 2014

Comment: You still never told us whether or not you might have the empty string in `Closed Date` and whether you want to handle this case.  Please learn to ask better questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for SQL Server to include empty string ('')

```
-->> SQL Server
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE [Closed Date] IS NULL OR [Closed Date] = ''

SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE ISNULL([Closed Date],'') = ''
```

Comment: @lad2025 what do you mean by SARG-able ?

Comment: If exist index on Closed Date, query optimizer will skip it

Comment: @lad2025 oh i see, i didn't know that yet, i always use `ISNULL` with that empty string logic.. thanks for that very important tips , anyways i modified my answer.